# Integration test run twice . Once due to FailSafe plugin for Jacoco and another due to Jbehave maven plugin

Tags: java, pom.xml, jacoco, jbehave, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have this pom file for the restful web service java project , where in we were using the Jbehave maven plugin for running integration tests and generating test execution reports . As part of a new process , i had to implement the Jacoco in project in the same pom file [ using Surefire and Failsafe plugins ] to generate code coverage reports . Now the issue is that the integration test cases are running twice causing issues in the Test Db's [ once for Jbehave and another time for Jacoco FailSafe plugin ] . IS there a way to modify the pom file to ensure Jacoco FailSafe as well as Jbehave runs as a single goal generating their respective reports [ i.e integration tests are executed only once ]

Tried commenting out either the Jacoco fail safe goal or Jbehave in which case integration tests are run only once , but unable to find a way to modify the pom file to make sure both goals get executed but integration test case is run only once

Pom file configuration if possible to make sure both Jbehave maven plugin as well as Jacoco failsafe plugin goals are executed but the integration test is run only once

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
<artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>$(jbehave.core.version)</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </configuration>
 </execution>

 <execution>
  <id>embeddable-stories</id>
  <phase>integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
      <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration> 
    <includes>
      <include>**/Stories.java</include>  
    </includes>


    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
        <executions>
            <!-- The Executions required by unit tests are omitted. -->
            <!--
                Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed.
            -->
            <execution>
                <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                    <!--
                        Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                        for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                    -->
                    <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!--
                Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after
                integration tests have been run.
            -->
            <execution>
                <id>post-integration-test</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                    <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>


    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <executions>
            <!--
                Ensures that both integration-test and verify goals of the Failsafe Maven
                plugin are executed.
            -->
            <execution>
                <id>integration-tests</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
                    <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                    <includes>
                       <include>**/Stories.java</include>  
                    </includes>             
                    <!--
                        Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests property
                        is true
                    -->
                    <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: without seeing the pom file how can anyone guess?

Comment: Sorry  here is the code